# Chrome extension popup window not showing tooltip like arrow

Tags: google-chrome-extension

While developing chrome extension I found out that the popup window which open doesn't have arrow pointing to icon like tooltip [popup window snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI7zr.png) while the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/user_interface/#popup) shows the window with arrow [document popup window snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOSUg.png). Is it removed? How can I replicate it

Comment: It was removed long time ago. You can't replicate it.

Comment: ok thanks, extension docs should be updated as per